# JW Player not working with Meteor.js

Tags: meteor, jwplayer, meteorite

I am trying to get JW Player to work inside Meteor.js.  I have tried both cloud-hosted and self-hosted and have not been able to get the player to show.  I'm not sure if there is a conflict using the two together.  It seems that it should be pretty straight forward but I just can't get it to work.  Any suggestions would be great.

Thanks

```
<head>
<title>Mysite</title>

<script src="http://jwpsrv.com/library/mytoken.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='my-video'></div>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    jwplayer('my-video').setup({
        file: 'http://localhost:3000/mymp3.mp3',
        width: '640',
        height: '360'
    });
    </script>

</body>
```

Here is an error message that I am getting:

Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: `"http://167.206.59.228/2-2573/a348fe94-6cbf-458f-8d56-8b69e6091c42_25.152.50.88/5.2.992971814237535". 167.206.59.228/:1`

`Request URL:http://167.206.59.228/2-2573/ec00f5c8-61a2-493b-a2e6-943f52ac381f_25.152.26.118/5.2.5313433578703552
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Host:167.206.59.228
Referer:http://localhost:3000/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36
Response Headersview parsed
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: PorchLight/6.0.20061.1302
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: Close
Content-Length: 1`

Comment: Please provide a link if possible?

Comment: I am hosting on a local host on a Mac.

Comment: Can you put something up? Really hard to tell without that.

Comment: I put an error message up.  The main.html file above is the only file I have added.  The mp3 is in the public folder.  Meteor.js setup via meteorite.  What else can I show you to help?

Comment: Where does that address get generated from?

Comment: I'm using Chrome, in the inspect elements console.  This is the message that shows.  When I click on the link provided it shows what I posted above.

Comment: What time of a file is "ttp://167.206.59.228/2-2573/a348fe94-6cbf-458f-8d56-8b69e6091c42_25.152.50.88/5.2.992971814237535". 167.206.59.228/:1" supposed to be?

Comment: I don't know.  I thought I was the one asking the question here.  :)

Comment: should that mp3 be hosted on 167.206.59.228 too? if that's client side html it's going to try to access localhost on the client pc instead of the server.

Comment: I really need to see a link to be able to figure out what is going on here.

Comment: I will try to get it online and post a link.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meteor does things differently than you'd expect. There is a Meteor way to build what you want. I've built a working demo based on your code:
https://github.com/michaelbishop/so-jwplayer

Let me try and explain step by step what I changed.

Meteor really likes templates. To do it the Meteor way, move the video div `<div id='my-video'></div>` to a template:

```
<template name="video">
    <div id='my-video'></div>
</template>
```

This allows you to operate on the template and do things like setup events or run javascript.

Next, move the player code into a file with the extension of `.js`:

```
jwplayer('my-video').setup({
    file: 'http://localhost:3000/mymp3.mp3',
    width: '640',
    height: '360'
});
```

You'll want the video player code to act upon the template after the page has been rendered and the library has been loaded like so:

```
Template.video.rendered = function () {
    jwplayer('my-video').setup({
        file: 'http://localhost:3000/mymp3.mp3',
        width: '640',
        height: '360'
    });
};
```

There is a also a created method (`Template.video.created`), but it won't work because the page hasn't been loaded yet and so the javascript library hasn't been loaded yet. You need the jwplayer setup code to execute after the page has loaded and the library is available.

Finally, static files, like `mymp3.mp3` need to be placed in the `public` folder. I found a open source mp3 and used that for the example.

Hope that helps! Good luck!

Comment: Just a note, make sure you `return` the `jwplayer` function so that it is injected in to the template. Hopefully this helps somebody

Comment: @supajp can you explain further? There is nothing in the documentation that suggests that:
http://docs.meteor.com/#template_rendered